# Issues posting data

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert data to a Wordpress database from a form using the post method. Beofre inserting (code will go where comment is) I'm trying to print the results to screen. When I test my code to collect this data from the form it errors only on one field for some reason. The others post correctly so I'm at a bit of a loss. Below is the code:

```
global $mydb;
echo '<form name="newProducts" method="post">';
$output = "<div>";
// array of column names
$table_name = $mydb->prefix . '`my-table-names`';
foreach ( $mydb->get_col( "DESC " . $table_name, 0 ) as $column_name ) {
        if($column_name!='id'){
          $table_name = $mydb->prefix . '`my-table-names`';
           $field_name = $column_name;
           $getSpecColNameOne = $mydb->get_var($mydb->prepare( "SELECT {$field_name} FROM {$table_name} WHERE id=%d", 0));
           $output .= '<div>';
           $output .= '<div>' . $getSpecColNameOne . '</div>';
           $output .= '<div><input name="' . $column_name . '" type="text" value=""></div>';
           $output .= '</div>';
        }   
}

$output .= '</div>'; 
echo $output;
    $_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $_POST );
    echo '<div class="btnWrapper">';
    echo '<input class="btn border-width-0 btn-text-skin btn-color-jevc btn-square btn-icon-left adduserBtn" type="submit" name="btnSubmit">';
echo '</form>';

if ($_POST) {

    $skipKeys = array(
                    'btnSubmit',
                    'id',
                 );

foreach($_POST as $key =>$value){

        if(!in_array($key,$skipKeys)){
            ///insert into db here////////
            echo '</br>';
            echo"Key:"; 
            print_r ($key);
            echo '</br>';
            echo"value:"; 
            print_r ($value);
        }
    }
}
```

The output I get if I don't fill out column_1 looks like this:

```
Key:column_1
value:
Key:column_2
value:Input Test 2
Key:column_3
value:Input Test 3
```

However, if I fill in data into column_1 input field it errors and I get redirected to a 404 page.

column_1 html output looks ok:

```
<input name="column_1" type="text" value="">
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: There isn't any code that tries to insert/update the database.

Comment: @colburton Hi, yes I should have tried to explain better, I intend to put that where the comment is. Right now I'm trying to get all the data back to print out to screen correctly first but it fails on the first field only.

Comment: OK. Then 1. find out what the error actually is. error.log might have some clues. 2. Look in the browser, what it is sending to the server.